# react-native parent prop not set

Tags: javascript, pointers, react-native, parent-child

I am setting my parent state (Login.js) from a child element's Props (MyTextField.js). From the child-element, the Prop's state says it is set (i.e username), but from the parent's perspective (Login.js), the state is not set. I'm very confused.
From MyTextField, the following is defined in the change_text(text) function

```
this.props.parent.state
```

But from Login.js 's login() function, the following is undefined:

```
this.state
```

they should be pointing to the same thing.

**MyTextField.js**

```
export default class MyTextField extends Component 
{
  constructor(props) 
  {
    super(props);
    this.state                  = {text: props.text, style:styles.unfocused};
    this.state[this.props.name] = '';
  }

  change_text(text)
  {
    this.setState({text:text});
    if(this.props.parent && this.props.name)
    {
      this.props.parent.state[this.props.name] = text;
    }
    else
      console.log('no parent or name');
  }

render() 
{
return (        
<TextInput style={this.state.style} multiline={false} maxLength={100} onFocus={() => this.setState({style:styles.focused}) } onBlur={() => this.setState({style:styles.unfocused}) } onChangeText={(text) => this.change_text(text)} value={this.state.text} placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
/>)
}
}


MyTextField.propTypes = 
{
  text:         React.PropTypes.string,
  parent:       React.PropTypes.object,
  name:         React.PropTypes.string
};
```

**Login.js**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
    import { View, Text, Button, TextInput,TouchableHighlight,StatusBar,StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import MyButton    from './MyButton';
import MyTextField from './MyTextField';

export default class Login extends Component 
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state =
    {
      username:'',
      password:'',
    };
  }

  login()
  {
    console.log('login',JSON.stringify(this.state,null,2));
  }
render()       
{
 return (
 <View style={{flex: 1,flexDirection: 'column',justifyContent: 'space-between',margin:10}}>
  <View style={{backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
  <MyTextField name='username' placeholder="User Name" parent={this} />
  <MyTextField name='password' placeholder="Password"  parent={this} />
  <MyButton onPress={this.login} title='Login'/>
  </View>
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This reason the parent's state (Login.js) was accessible from the child (MyTextInput.js) and not the Login.js, is because I needed to **bind** the Login.js's login function to itself (Why I don't know), since I never called **bind** on the child (MyTextInput.js) and the child worked just fine.

```
this.login = this.login.bind(this);
```